# SQL Joining a table twice to extract related data

Tags: sql

Can't figure out this query. I have 4 tables Person, Pupil, Relation and House. The person table contains both pupils and parents, I have a join table called relation which links pupils to parents.

I am trying to get a list of all the parents for the IDS I have for the pupils. The pn alias should represent the Pupil details and the rp should represent the parent details. I have the following code but am not sure you can link to a table twice, like I have done with PERSON so should I be using a subquery or am I missing something really obvious?

```
SELECT pn.pk_PersonID, 
       pn.Title, 
       pn.Forename, 
       pn.Surname, 
       rp.Title, 
       rp.Forename, 
       rp.Surname, 
       pn.PreferredForename, 
       pn.DoB, 
       pn.Gender, 
       h.House, 
       p.Form, 
       p.BoardingStatus, 
       p.Tutor, 
       h.Housemaster 
  FROM PUPIL AS p 
         LEFT JOIN PERSON AS pn ON p.pk_PupilID = pn.pk_PersonID  
         LEFT JOIN HOUSE AS h ON p.fk_DepartmentID = h.fk_DepartmentID 
         LEFT JOIN RELATION AS r ON p.pk_PupilID = r.fk_PersonID 
         LEFT JOIN PERSON AS rp ON r.fk_RelatedPersonID = rp.pk_PersonID 
 WHERE p.pk_PupilID IN('" & pks & "') AND ORDER BY pn.Forename ASC
```

Comment: Query looks fine to me.. There is no reason you can't use 2 separate instances of the same table, as long as they're aliased differently. Are the results not as you expected?

Comment: Remove the `AND` before `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Can you link a table twice?  Yes.  That being said, without seeing some sample data, and a description of how your current query isn't working for you, it's hard to say what might be wrong with it.  Are you getting a syntax error?  Too much data?  Too little data?  Also, what is `pks`?

Comment: Thanks Guys, I've got it working, it was the AND..... hate linking to multiple tables, now I have to add a further couple to this query to get all the info I want.